# Getting web elements using Jsoup

Tags: java, web, web-scraping, jsoup

I'm trying to use `Jsoup` to get stock data from a website called morningstar. I've looked at other forums and haven't been able to find out what's wrong.

I'm trying to do more advanced scrapping of data but I can't seem to even get the price. I either get null returned or nothing at all.

I am aware of other languages and APIs but I'd like to use `Jsoup` as it seems to be very capable.

Here's what I have so far:

```
public class Scrape {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String URL = "http://www.morningstar.com/stocks/xnas/aapl/quote.html";
        Document d = new Document(URL);
        try{
            d = Jsoup.connect(URL).get();
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Element stuff = d.select("#idPrice gr_text_bigprice").first();
        System.out.println("Price of AAPL: " + stuff);
        }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you positive the data isn't generated dynamically by javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Since the content is created dynamically using javascript, you could use a headless browser like HtmlUnit https://sourceforge.net/projects/htmlunit/

The information regarding the price, etc. is embedded in an iFrame, so we first grab the (also dynamically build) iFrame link and parse the iFrame afterwards.

```
java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("com.gargoylesoftware").setLevel(java.util.logging.Level.OFF);

final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME);
webClient.getOptions().setCssEnabled(false);
webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);
webClient.getOptions().setTimeout(1000);

HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("http://www.morningstar.com/stocks/xnas/aapl/quote.html");

Document doc = Jsoup.parse(page.asXml());

String title = doc.select(".r_title").select("h1").text();

String iFramePath = "http:" + doc.select("#quote_quicktake").select("iframe").attr("src");

page = webClient.getPage(iFramePath);

doc = Jsoup.parse(page.asXml());

System.out.println(title + " | Last Price [$]: " + doc.select("#last-price-value").text());
```

prints:

```
Apple Inc | Last Price [$]: 98.63
```

The javascript engine in HtmlUnit is rather slow (above code takes about 18 seconds on my machine), so it might be useful to look into other javascript engines/headless browsers ([phantomJs](http://phantomjs.org/), etc.; check this list of options: https://github.com/dhamaniasad/HeadlessBrowsers) to enhance the performance, but HtmlUnit gets the job done. You could also try to filter non relevant scripts, images, etc. with a custom `WebConnectionWrapper`:

http://htmlunit.10904.n7.nabble.com/load-parse-speedup-tp22735p22738.html