# Android - Parse JS generated urls with JSOUP

Tags: javascript, java, android, web-scraping, jsoup

im trying to parse url generated by Bootstrap`s Bootpage.js which looks like
https://example.com/#page-2
but JSOUP cant parse it and showing main url.
how to get normal link from Bootpage or how to make JSOUP to parse it.

Parsing code:

```
Jsoup.connect("https://example.com/#page-2").followRedirects(true).get();
```

Comment: Jsoup has no js engine. Without a link to a real website, it is hard to help, but the page is probably generated dynamically, so JSoup is not the right tool here (check the behaviour in your browser with disabled javascript). Try it with js capable headless browsers like HtmlUnit, PhantomJS, ...

Comment: without JS it shows blank, not redirecting to url

Comment: So have you tried it with HtmlUnit? You can still use JSoup to parse the result (see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37670840/getting-web-elements-using-jsoup/37676584#37676584).

Comment: nope, does not work, someone said it`s framework hashed links.
Bootpage`s framework, so is there any way to, well, handle hashed links

Comment: Still not willing to share a link?

Comment: http://srulad.com/#page-2
well, its not english website :D

Comment: its actually redirecting directly to page 2 from link, which means? idk :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(***See UPDATE below***, first/accepted solution didn't met the android requirement, but is left for reference.)

---

Desktop Solution

HtmlUnit doesn't seem able to handle this site (often the case, lately). So I don't have a plain java solution either, but you could use [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/): [download the binary](http://phantomjs.org/download.html) for your os, create a script file, start the process from within your java code and parse the output with a dom parser like [jsoup](https://jsoup.org/).

**Script file (here called simple.js):**

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
var fs = require('fs');
var system = require('system');

var url = "";
var fileName = "output";
// first parameter: url
// second parameter: filename for output
console.log("args length: " + system.args.length);

if (system.args.length > 1) {
    url=system.args[1];
}
if (system.args.length > 2){
    fileName=system.args[2];
}
if(url===""){
    phantom.exit();
}

page.settings.userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.120 Safari/537.36';
page.settings.loadImages = false; 

page.open(url, function(status) {
    console.log("Status: " + status);
    if(status === "success") {
        var path = fileName+'.html';
        fs.write(path, page.content, 'w');
    }
    phantom.exit();
});
```

**Java code (example to get title and cover-url):**

```
try {
    //change path to phantomjs binary and your script file
    String outputFileName = "srulad";
    String phantomJSPath = "phantomjs" + File.separator + "bin" + File.separator + "phantomjs";
    String scriptFile = "simple.js";

    String urlParameter = "http://srulad.com/#page-2";

    new File(outputFileName+".html").delete();

    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(phantomJSPath + " " + scriptFile + " " + urlParameter + " " + outputFileName);
    process.waitFor();

    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(new File(outputFileName + ".html"),"UTF-8"); // output.html is created by phantom.js, same path as page.js
    Elements elements = doc.select("#list_page-2 > div");

    for (Element element : elements) {
        System.out.println(element.select("div.l-description.float-left > div:nth-child(1) > a").first().attr("title"));
        System.out.println(element.select("div.l-image.float-left > a > img.lazy").first().attr("data-original"));
    }
} catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**Output:**

```
სიყვარული და მოწყალება / Love & Mercy
http://srulad.com/assets/uploads/42410_Love_and_Mercy.jpg
მუზა / The Muse
http://srulad.com/assets/uploads/43164_large_qRzsimNz0eDyFLFJcbVLIxlqii.jpg
...
```

---

### UPDATE

Parsing of websites with javascript based dynamic content in Android is possible using [WebView](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html) and jsoup. 
The following example app uses a javascript enabled WebView to render a Javascript dependent website. With a JavascriptInterface the html source is returned, parsed with jsoup and as a proof of concept the titles and the urls to the cover-images are used to populate a ListView. The buttons decrement or increment the page number triggering an update of the ListView. *Note: tested on an Android 5.1.1/API 22 device.*

add internet permission to your AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/page_down"
            android:id="@+id/buttonDown"
            android:layout_weight="0.5" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/page_up"
            android:id="@+id/buttonUp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_weight="0.5" />
</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private final Handler uiHandler = new Handler();
    private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    private ArrayList<String> entries = new ArrayList<>();
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    private class JSHtmlInterface {
        @android.webkit.JavascriptInterface
        public void showHTML(String html) {
            final String htmlContent = html;

            uiHandler.post(
                new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(htmlContent);
                        Elements elements = doc.select("#online_movies > div > div");
                        entries.clear();
                        for (Element element : elements) {
                            String title = element.select("div.l-description.float-left > div:nth-child(1) > a").first().attr("title");
                            String imgUrl = element.select("div.l-image.float-left > a > img.lazy").first().attr("data-original");
                            entries.add(title + "\n" + imgUrl);
                        }
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }
            );
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, entries);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Loading","Please wait...", true);
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);

        try {
            final WebView browser = new WebView(this);
            browser.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            browser.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_NONE,null);
            browser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            browser.getSettings().setBlockNetworkImage(true);
            browser.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(false);
            browser.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
            browser.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(false);
            browser.getSettings().setGeolocationEnabled(false);
            browser.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);

            browser.addJavascriptInterface(new JSHtmlInterface(), "JSBridge");

            browser.setWebViewClient(
                new WebViewClient() {

                    @Override
                    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                        progressDialog.show();
                        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                        browser.loadUrl("javascript:window.JSBridge.showHTML('<html>'+document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML+'</html>');");
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }
            );

            findViewById(R.id.buttonDown).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    uiHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            int page = Integer.parseInt(browser.getUrl().split("-")[1]);
                            int newPage = page > 1 ? page-1 : 1;
                            browser.loadUrl("http://srulad.com/#page-" + newPage);
                            browser.loadUrl(browser.getUrl()); // not sure why this is needed, but doesn't update without it on my device
                            if(getSupportActionBar()!=null) getSupportActionBar().setTitle(browser.getUrl());
                        }
                    });
                }
            });

            findViewById(R.id.buttonUp).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    uiHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            int page = Integer.parseInt(browser.getUrl().split("-")[1]);
                            int newPage = page+1;
                            browser.loadUrl("http://srulad.com/#page-" + newPage);
                            browser.loadUrl(browser.getUrl()); // not sure why this is needed, but doesn't update without it on my device
                            if(getSupportActionBar()!=null) getSupportActionBar().setTitle(browser.getUrl());
                        }
                    });
                }
            });

            browser.loadUrl("http://srulad.com/#page-1");
            if(getSupportActionBar()!=null) getSupportActionBar().setTitle(browser.getUrl());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: wow, amazing, thanks very much, but one problem here, site is not mine, i can`t paste script.js in main server so where to paste it?

Comment: still, i will flag this as accepted answer because no other solution is found and for those who has their own sites like this, its super helpful solution.

Comment: The script file runs on your local machine, it is just the way you write the instructions for PhantomJS, so no need for server access.

Comment: well, i did not understood your code, maybe cuz im beginner in studio and so... besides, it required external sources. well, i achieved it with webView, initializing next page onPostExecute so its always ready to go. Anyway, thanks for amazing support and spending time for solve my problem !

Comment: Oh, my bad, once I ditched HtmlUnit I forgot about the android context. Your comment regarding running a server (as a middleware) makes sense now. Will try to find an alternative, that works with android.

Comment: See update in answer: added a working solution for parsing javascript dependent pages.

Comment: Cleverer approach, this means SO interesting ! thanks !