# Scan complete page with JSOUP

Tags: java, android, jsoup

I would like to parse a complete page with JSOUP .I have done in the past, parts of a page, but not a complete page. Here is for parts:

```
String url = "http://www.billboard.com/charts/artist-100";
doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
Elements names = doc.select("div.chart-row__title > h2.chart-row__song");
for (Element p : names)
    Names.add(p.text().toString());
```

Comment: If `doc.toString()` is incomplete, than you need other tools (like HtmlUnit, or for Android use WebView) to render the dynamic content: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/jsoup/4632/parsing-javascript-generated-pages#t=201610050741484704039

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android - Parse JS generated urls with JSOUP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39140121/android-parse-js-generated-urls-with-jsoup)