# Jsoup with JavaScript dependent web page?

Tags: java, android, jsoup

So I'm having trouble formulating the correct syntax for selecting this element from a webpage. Here is what the path looks like on the Inspect Element Interface on Firefox

[image]

And here's what my current code looks like:

```
    Element prices = doc.select("body[class =en page-type-search page-type-group-shelf og ress] " +
                    "div#wrap " +
                    "div#main-wrap " +
                    "div#jalapeno-template " +
                    "div[class=zone zone3 wgrid-10of12 wgrid-6of8 wgrid-4of4] " +
                    "section#shelf-page " +
                    "div#shelf-thumbs " +
                    "div.shelf-thumbs " +
                    "div.price-current " +
                    "span.product-price-analytics").first();

            String priceOne = prices.attr("data-analytics-value");
```

And just to be incredibly clear, the attribute that I'm wanting is the 'data-analytics-value' because it gives an exact price.

I think that I have all the correct syntax so what am I doing wrong? When I run the program it gives me a nullPointerException. Any help is appreciated!

[**Update**] I changed princeOne to doc.toString() and its saying the the web browser is not running javascript and that JavaScript is required to view the walmart website, any work arounds?

Comment: Use a WebView to grab the rendered page, then parse with jsoup.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android - Parse JS generated urls with JSOUP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39140121/android-parse-js-generated-urls-with-jsoup)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying with no luck using Android's WebView, I *accidentally* found a solution in setting my userAgent, all I did was change the

```
    Jsoup.connect(url).get();
```

line to

```
    Jsoup.connect(url).userAgent("YOUR_USER_AGENT_HERE").get();
```

and it worked like a charm. Thanks for the reply anyway Fred!