# Jsoup not returning data of redirected link

Tags: android, jsoup

I am loading one website which redirects to new webpage as soon as it finishes.I want that the redirected website should be parsed and returned by jsoup. following is code which I am using in Android Studio:

```
class RetrieveListTask1 extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<String>> {
    Document doc;
    protected List<String> doInBackground(String... urls) {

        try {
             doc = Jsoup.connect("https://mahabhulekh.maharashtra.gov.in/Pune/Pune.html").get();
            Log.d("Element : ",doc.toString());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

the Above mentioned link redirects to https://mahabhulekh.maharashtra.gov.in/Pune/Home.aspx .you can check it.
I cannot load https://mahabhulekh.maharashtra.gov.in/Pune/Home.aspx dirrectly as if I load it directly it transfers back to home page.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24907808/jsoup-get-redirected-url

Comment: It is not working @AngelKoh

Comment: Try to set the user-agent string to match your browser.

Comment: If the redirect is done with javascript, call the page with HtmlUnit, then parse with jsoup: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37676584/1661938

Answer (score 0):

The redirect is actually performed via a Javascript code submitting a form.
Hopefully, we can submit form with Jsoup.

```
// Load document as usual...
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://mahabhulekh.maharashtra.gov.in/Pune/Pune.html").get();

// Find the form
FormElement form = (FormElement) doc.getElementById("frmrd");
if (form == null) {
    // Form not found...
} else {
    doc = form.submit().execute().parse();
    System.out.println("Document base uri: " + doc.baseUri());
    System.out.println("Content: " + doc.outerHtml());
}
```

#### OUTPUT (truncated)

```
Document base uri: https://mahabhulekh.maharashtra.gov.in/Pune/Home.aspx
Content: <!doctype html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
  <title>

</title> 
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script> 
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script> 
  <link href="Style/MainStyle.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> 
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script> 
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script> 
  <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function divisionName() {
            switch (document.getElementById('param').value) {
                case "1":
                    document.getElementById('divisionName').innerHTML = 'अमरावती विभाग';
...
```

#### See also:

- [How to fetch efficiently an HTML document on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35695852/363573)
- [Filling a form with Jsoup : a real life example.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35267768/363573)